# Win32 C++ How to handle LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH in a ListView subclass?

Tags: c, listview, winapi, subclass, win32gui

I have a ListView whose columns I'd like to resize in relation to the size of the ListView itself (which is sized based on the window size). The ListView is subclassed with a seperate `WNDPROC` in which `WM_NOTIFY` is being used to handle other messages.

To size the header columns I'm using `ListView_SetColumnWidth()`, however this only works when I deactivate the seperate ListView `WNDPROC` or remove from it the `WM_NOTIFY` handling.

I've tried handling `LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` manually in both the `WNDPROC` for both the ListView and its header to see if the message is getting passed through, but to no avail.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed; any help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, the `WM_NOTIFY` in my ListView `WNDPROC`:

```
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        UINT debugval = (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code);
        switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
        {
            case HDN_BEGINTRACK:
            {
                return TRUE;  //Prevent manual resizing.
                break;
            }
            case LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH:
            {
                ::MessageBox(hwnd, L"test", L"test", MB_OK);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Does your custom `WNDPROC` call the default window procedure for messages it doesn't manually handle? Like `LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH`?

Comment: `CallWindowProc()` for the default case from the ListView `WNDPROC` goes to the main `WNDPROC` and from the header's `WNDPROC` to the ListView's.

Comment: It works when you remove the WM_NOTIFY handling, so obviously there is a WM_NOTIFY message involved, and it works when you change what you do with that message. What did you change?

Comment: I only handle `HDN_BEGINTRACK` in the ListView `WNDPROC`. When I add in `LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` with some code, nothing happens.

Comment: What does your ListView WNDPROC do when it receives a WM_NOTIFY? Not "does it handle it or not" but what functions does it call? And when you remove the handling, what functions does it call then?

Comment: I've added the code to the question for ease.

Comment: You must pass *all* messages that you don't handle to the subclassed window.  Including WM_NOTIFY + LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH.

Comment: Is `LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` even sent by way of a `WM_NOTIFY` message? Normally, things that *are* have an `N` before the underscore.

Comment: And, sometimes, the `MessageBox()` call can interfere with the message pump; try using something like `::Beep(1000,200)` instead.

Comment: I've managed to sort it by adding a `default` clause to the `WM_NOTIFY` case containing a `CallWindowProc()` to my main `WNDPROC`. Still unsure as to why I'm unable to handle the `LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` though. I'm getting painting issues when resizing my columns now so will have to look into that.

Comment: @AdrianMole I tried using `::Beep(1000, 200)` instead but it had no effect.

Comment: Well, if `Beep()` is not doing anything, then maybe that's because your `WNDPROC` is **not** getting `LVM_SETCOLUMNWDITH` through `WM_NOTIFY`. Just check that `Beep(1000,200);` makes a noise when you put it somewhere in your code that you *know* executes.

Comment: It's getting some form of message (see my previous comment). I tested `LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` in Control Spy where it seems `LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` follows three `WM_NOTIFY` notifications. Update on the paint issues: They seemed to arise from the scrollbar flashing in and out of existence when resizing, I disabled scrolling and now the header looks fine when resizing.

Comment: @SyntheticAscension Obviously, setting the column width causes some WM_NOTIFY message to be sent as a side effect (maybe the header (which is a separate window) is telling the listbox that its size changed). And when you delete the WM_NOTIFY by not passing it to the listbox's WNDPROC, you are causing that to stop working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` is its own separate message, it is NOT carried through `WM_NOTIFY`, like you have coded for.  You need to move `case LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` into the outer `switch` instead.  And make sure you are calling `CallWindowProc()` or `DefSubclassProc()` (depending on how you are creating the subclass) for ALL messages you don't want to discard.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
switch (uMsg)
{
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        UINT code = (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code);
        switch (code)
        {
            case HDN_BEGINTRACK:
            {
                return TRUE;  //Prevent manual resizing.
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    case LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH:
    {
        ...
        break;
    }
}

return CallWindowProc(..., hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
or
return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a ListView whose columns I'd like to resize in relation to the size of the ListView itself (which is sized based on the window size).

So in the main window you need to modify the size of the Listview through [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos), and modify the size of the ListView columns through [`ListView_SetColumnWidth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_setcolumnwidth).

Like the following code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        int cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
        int cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);
        SetWindowPos(Instructions_ListView, NULL, cxClient / 3, cyClient / 4, cxClient / 5, cyClient / 2, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        ListView_SetColumnWidth(Instructions_ListView, 0, cxClient / 10);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Then, in the `WNDPROC` function of ListView, `LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH` is its own unique message, not belonging to `WM_NOTIFY`.And handle other default messages through [`DefSubclassProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-defsubclassproc).

So you can refer to the following code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ListProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        UINT debugval = (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code);
        switch (debugval)
        {
        case HDN_BEGINTRACK:
            return true;
        }
        break;
    }
    case LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH:
        OutputDebugString(L"LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH triggered\n");
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Finally, it works for me:

[image]